# How to organize scripts and tools under ~/bin in directories, but have them in $PATH?

Tags: bash, executable, paths, .profile

I always have `~/bin` added to the `$PATH` in my `~/.profile`. As is default in Ubuntu.

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

However, when trying out software, hacking together a script, or testing new software that has no PPA's, makefiles and such, I prefer to organize them in directories. For example (I have about twelve of these projects in my ~/bin at this moment):

```
ber@audrey:~ ☙ ls bin/replicatorg-0033/
contributors.txt  examples  lib-i686    license.txt  readme.txt   scripts        todo.txt
docs              lib       lib-x86_64  machines     replicatorg  skein_engines  tools
```

This is some java application. `replicatorg` is the executable.

Now, I could do four things, but I am looking for another, better way:

1. Symlink the exectuable in `~/bin`. `ln -s bin/replicatorg-0033/replicatorg bin/replicatorg`. This sometimes works, not in this case. The application is poorly written and expects libraries relative to its binary: it will not run when symlinked or copied out of its directory.
2. Add every subdirectory to $PATH as well. But that means editing ~/.profile everytime I move, download or git-clone new directories.
3. Install the applications properly systemwide by creating a makefile/install script. Seen as that most of the applications are quick hacks, ugly, in development, scripts and tools, that is not a good idea, IMHO.
4. Move all the contents of ~/replicatorg-0033/ into ~/bin. Right.

So: how do you organize your `~/bin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create a separate directory for holding packages (`~/apps`). If there is a program that I want to have in my `$PATH`, I either create a symlink in `~/bin` or create a shell script wrapper in `~/bin` if the program in question does not like symbolic links:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ~/apps/package/bin/someprogram "$@"
```

For larger packages with many programs, adding the directory to your `$PATH` may be preferable to avoid a `~/bin` directory with many symlinks to a single project. This depends on your personal preferences though.

Comment: I like the notion of wrapper shellscripts. It goes well with my other practice to keep vanilla source of applications in ~/src. Thanks!

Comment: It's better to prepend `exec ` to the command, so the wrapper script process is replaced with the app you wish to run. That way you won't have a wrapper script process uselessly hanging in the process tree, and you will preserve the exit code of the app.

Answer (score 4):

1. Add every subdirectory to $PATH as well. **But that means editing ~/.profile everytime I move, download or git-clone new directories.**

No need to edit every time, try something like this:

```
if [ -f ~/bin ]; then
   for i in $( find ~/bin -type d ); do
     PATH=$PATH:$i
   done
fi
```